# m_context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { clazz }, properties) throws illegal annotations exception

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb

I have a class IsoMessage-

```
public class IsoMessage
{
  private boolean binBitmap;

 public IsoMessage() {}

 public void setBinaryBitmap(boolean paramBoolean)
  {
    this.binBitmap = paramBoolean;
  }

  public boolean isBinaryBitmap()
  {
    return this.binBitmap;
  }
}
```

why does it throw illegal annotationexception while creating JAXBContext?

Comment: For me it works. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Also post the exception.